# Fetch data from Firestore to StatelessWidget StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I do have a callable Stateless Widget for fetching the data of Number/Count of Users Followers.
However, whenever I try to print in the widget if `snapshot.hasData` it always says `snapshot is: false` is it returns false.

```
class UserFollowersWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserFollowersWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: FirestoreHelper.usersFollowerCount(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
       // the snapshot.hasData prints as false.
        return Text("snapshot is: ${snapshot.hasData}");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my callable stream for my StreamBuilder.

```
static usersFollowerCount() {
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("user_activities")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection("followers")
          .doc("users_followers")
          .snapshots();
    } catch (e) {
      print("usersFollowerCount Error : $e");
    }
  }
```

So basically, I want to access the array document field of `users_followers` named `userFollowersStats` and get the values inside of its array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is that your `usersFollowerCount` function is not returning the stream correctly. You should return the stream that you create using `snapshots()’.

```
static Stream<DocumentSnapshot>usersFollowerCount(){
try {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("user_activities")
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .collection("followers")
    .doc("users_followers")
    .snapshots();
 } catch (e) {
    print("usersFollowerCount Error : $e");
    return Stream.empty();
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi sanchit, the solution is correct! Thank you! But would be better if you remove the ``dot(.)`` in the ``userFollowerCount()`` function, I think that was a typo of yours. I am now accepting this as a correct answer since it worked on my end. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @jpg.hue for pointing out the typo in the code, I have edited it for future references and I'm glad that I was able to help you. Cheers :)